# Jquery : Put line break (press enter button) on entering certain character in text area

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $('.mydesc').keyup(function () {
 var len = $(this).val().length;
if(len == 63){
    //put line break here 
}           
 });
```

on reaching 63 characters including space the cursor should b moved to next line
(effect when i get enter button)

how can i do it in jquery ?

Comment: Some feedback on the answer below would be great. Makes all the effort worthwhile :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add line break using `\n` when reach `63` characters:

```
$('.mydesc').keyup(function () {
    var len = $(this).val().length;
    if (len == 63) {
        this.value += '\n';
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9bKbQ/)**

Comment: but this does not check second line

Comment: requirement is that it should check for each line

Answer (score 0):

do something like this:

```
if(len == 63){
    $(this).val($(this).val() + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/9bKbQ/5/

```
$('.mydesc').keyup(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var val = $this.val();
    var lines = val.split('\n');
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        var line = lines[i];
        while (line.length > 5) {
            result.push(line.substring(0, 5));
            line = line.slice(5);
        }
        result.push(line);
    }
    $this.val(result.join('\n'));
});
```

Just change the 5's to the length you want.